# Issues with Twilio on Mobile Chrome Browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, twilio, mobile-chrome

was wondering if anyone may know if Twilio currently supports Chrome Mobile 79.0.3945? Our applications Sentry plugin has registered repeated error for 4 specific users of our running this version of Chrome Mobile on an Android Device. The error is coming from the Twilio audiohelper file and reads:

Error: This browser does not support audio output selection

And here is the exact user-agent data from the header.

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; SM-G960U) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.93 Mobile Safari/537.36

I'm confusing as Twilio's site says they support Android Chrome but is this particular version not supported? Any insights would help, Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Chrome 79 should not be a problem with this, but browsers run on a range of devices which may or may not have all the capabilities that the browser allows. I would recommend writing code to handle this kind of error if you are working with output selection. There's [more details about the audio methods and the errors they may produce in the documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/audiooutputcollection#audiooutputcollectionset-deviceid-deviceids).

Comment: Thanks philnash, we believe the error was caused because the users were using Chrome for Android which does not support the setSinkId functionality necessary for audio selection. We are planing to address browser functionality in a future sprint but can you tell me would this error halt device setup and thus not enable outbound calling or would it just prevent different audio output selection?

Comment: Okay, so what's the possible solution to this issue? I believe this issue is also affected by Mozilla browser

Comment: I actually believe that the message is merely a warning, not being able to set the output means it will use the browser’s default output and that you can’t change that. It’s a browser limitation so there’s nothing we can do to change that.